# list all packages from a repository in ubuntu / debian

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, repository

is there a command to see what packages are available from a certain ppa repository?

Answer (score 72):

Simple:

```
 grep -h -P -o "^Package: \K.*" /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_*_Packages | sort -u
```

Or more flexible:

```
grep-dctrl -sPackage . /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_*_Packages
```

For fancier querying, use `apt-cache policy` and `aptitude` [as described here](https://superuser.com/questions/132346/find-packages-installed-from-a-certain-repository-with-aptitude/138726#138726):

```
aptitude search '~O LP-PPA-gstreamer-developers'
```

Comment: Use `xzcat /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_*_Packages.xz | grep '^Package:'` if that package file is compressed.

Comment: You should put single quotes `'` around that `^Package:`. On zsh `^` has a special meaning.

Answer (score 27):

```
grep Package /var/lib/apt/lists/(repo name)_Packages
```

Comment: `ls /var/lib/apt/lists/*_binary-amd64_Packages | sed -E 's/.*\/([^\/_]*).*/\1/' | sort -u`

Comment: `cat /var/lib/apt/lists/AAA.BBB.com_*_Packages | grep '^Package: ' | cut -c 10- | sort -u | nl`

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for:

https://superuser.com/questions/132346/find-packages-installed-from-a-certain-repository-with-aptitude

Like it says, Synaptic Package Manager allows you to search by "origin".  This isn't programmatic, but it should give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun or if you do not trust the caches, you can query a source's declared packages from, well, the source. The repositories are pretty much websites, either HTTP or FTP.

Your system has source URLs, which you can query for specific architectures and binary/source parameters. Then you can query the specific architecture's package lists.

E.g., I use an excellent jRiver's media player *MediaCenter* on Pop!_OS. To query their *stable* repository, which I have configured, first find out the URL:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mediacenter26.list 
#MC
deb [arch=i386,amd64,armhf] http://dist.jriver.com/stable/mediacenter/ jessie main
```

Then grab the list location for the architecture which interests you. Note that the URL is formed following the pattern `<archive_url>/dists/<distro>/Release`:

```
$ curl -s http://dist.jriver.com/stable/mediacenter/dists/jessie/Release |
> grep "amd64/Packages$" |
> cut -d" " -f 4 |
> sort -u
main/binary-amd64/Packages
```

Finally, append the architecture's list path to the distribution and extract the package names from the lists of signatures:

```
$ curl -s http://dist.jriver.com/stable/mediacenter/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages |
> grep "^Package: " |
> cut -d" " -f2 |
> sort -u
mediacenter21
mediacenter22
mediacenter23
mediacenter24
mediacenter25
```

Naturally, tune or remove the `grep`|`cut`|`sort` filters to your taste. Remove `-s` (silent) parameter from `curl` to see diagnostics if needed.

... or use a [Synaptic package manager](https://github.com/mvo5/synaptic).

Comment: This is a very nice wrap up on repo architecture, coming in very useful, when you try to look into a repo from a non debian system. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Old thread, but thought it might help. Use awk, sort and uniq to grab only the packages and discard the Package repo checksums.

```
grep ^Package /var/lib/apt/lists/<repo you are interested in>* | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: `awk '/^Package: / {print $2}' /var/lib/apt/lists/PACKAGE_REPO | sort -u` should do the same

Answer (score 1):

For my use case I wanted a list of packages from multiple repos matching the same dist release, specifically Jessie. This host has multiple jessie repos configured, Dell's linux repo and the Debian archives for some dependencies.

I wound up with this, ahem, one-liner:

```
for p in $(dpkg -l | awk '/ii/{ print $2 }'); do for i in $(apt-cache policy "$p" | awk '/Installed/{ print $2}'); do apt-cache policy "$p" | grep -A1 '\*\*\*\ '$i'' | if grep -q jessie; then echo $p; fi; done; done
```

Quite ugly, as we need to run apt-cache twice, once to get the installed version of a package and a second time to match that installed version against the target repo, which conveniently can be matched by just "jessie" in this case.

If you remove the 'grep -q' you'll get output of the matched repo line as well for confirmation, or otherwise. You could adapt this match syntax to regex to match on multiple repos.