# Why can't i install mongodb 3.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 32bit?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt, mongodb

I have followed all the official istructions listed here:

[official page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

In detail, i have done:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

(seems ok)

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

(seems ok, as the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list is created with the right entry)

```
sudo apt-get update
```

(seems ok, as i see the repos in the list)

but when i do :

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

it always says "Can't find package mongodb-org".

If i do:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb
```

It works, but it doesn't install version 3.0 but version 2.4

I have tried multiple times to install 3.0 after removing / purging the 2.4 version, but with the same result: "Can't find package mongodb-org"

How can i install version 3.0 ?

**EDIT**

*apt-cache search mongodb* doesn't find anything regarding *mongodb-org*

This is the content of */etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list* :

```
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse
```

these are the lines resulting from *apt-get update* regarding mondodb:

```
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 InRelease
Trovato http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 Release.gpg
Trovato http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 Release
Trovato http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse Translation-it_IT
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse Translation-it
Ign http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse Translation-en
```

I'am running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit. Maybe the repo is only for x64? If it's the case, how can i install mongodb 3.0 on a 32 bit machine ? (i haven't seen anything regarding this dinstinction in the docs )

**EDIT 2**

So, it seems there are no 32 packages in those repos.
Now, where can i find them? I think it's stange as the docs ( [official docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) ) specify only this repo, and nothing is said about 32/64 bit differences.

Comment: Does `apt-cache search mongodb` find your package? Maybe it has another name?

Comment: Please post the contents of the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list` as well as the line from `apt-get update` showing this repo being checked?  The repo contains the mongodb-org meta-package for x64 Trusty, as seen here: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/multiverse/binary-amd64/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no 32 bits packages in those repositories:

Check for yourself, amd64:

```
wget -O - \
  http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.1/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages.gz \
  2>/dev/null | zless | grep ^Package
Package: mongodb-org-unstable
Package: mongodb-org-unstable-mongos
Package: mongodb-org-unstable-server
Package: mongodb-org-unstable-shell
Package: mongodb-org-unstable-tools
```

Whereas for i686, no packages are returned.

```
wget -O - \
  http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.1/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages.gz 2>/dev/null
```

Or if you prefer clicks, open a browser to that location:

```
xdg-open http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.1/multiverse/binary-i386/
```

Also, check [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/252333/list-all-packages-from-a-repository-in-ubuntu-debian).

Moreover, the vendor [discourages the use of 32 bit binaries for production use](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), probably due to its [limitations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/fundamentals/#what-are-the-limitations-of-32-bit-versions-of-mongodb):

> For production deployments, always run MongoDB on 64-bit systems.

Comment: i know the limtations: in fact in production and test we have a 64 bit machine. I need to install mongo 3.0 in my 32 bit develop machine ( i can't install 64 bit SO  as guest in my virtual machine due to hardware limits )

Comment: Well, if you are forced to use a machine incapable of running a 64bit VM that is required to do your job properly, you should raise this concern with your manager. [That or ...](http://dilbert.com/strip/1995-06-24)

Comment: No, this is my personal develop machine. I don't have a manager :) The fact is i'd like to know if it's possible or not to install mongo 3.x on a 32 bit machine. If it's possible (as it seems from the docs) i'd like to know if there is a repo to fetch the packages from. If it's not possible i'm going to evalutate what to do

Comment: Then **you** are your manager. Argument still holds.

Comment: I've searched with no success for 32 bit repos, so i accept your answer as the most helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Same situation. Solved by downloading 32 bit mongodb3 directly from here https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.1.tgz .

Answer (score 1):

based on mongdodb [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/) you can try to install the tarball installation. That is (taken from the docs):

1. download the binary files [here](https://www.mongodb.org/downloads) or using `curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.6.tgz`
2. extract the files `tar -zxvf mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.6.tgz`
3. copy extracted files

   ```
   mkdir -p mongodb
   cp -R -n mongodb-linux-i686-3.0.6/ mongodb
   ```
4. add it to PATH

   ```
   #example in ~/.bashrc
   export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH
   ```

**note** as noted in mongodb using this method will have some limitation

"This 32-bit legacy distribution does not include SSL encryption and is limited to around 2GB of data. In general you should use the 64 bit builds."

but in the end it is up to you.

Comment: This is the most accurate answer as it actually answers the OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

Add the repository using the above code.
Then run update command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then give a command to install mongodb giving all the parameters forcefully yes using

```
sudo apt-get install --force-yes mongodb
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you read the question you will see that he already tried that.